# Pod install shows the error like required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, afnetworking

I would like to update **`pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0.1'`** ,But my terminal shows the following error like when **pod install** command running

```
Specs satisfying the `AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 4.0.1), AFNetworking/NSURLSession (~> 3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

My podfile looks like the following

```
pod 'AFOAuth2Manager', '~> 3.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0.1'
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking 4.x version can only support iOS 9 and above. Your project should have deployment target of iOS 9 or above.

Comment: I already added the version   platform :ios, '10.0'  in my podfile.Still getting same error

Comment: what is the deployment target set in your project settings?

Comment: Check the target in framework project settings also. Dependency frameworks should also set to 9.0 or above

Comment: I have selected also in  target pane in xcode.General->Deployment Info->Deployment Target->10.0